# huggingface embedding large csv in batches

Tags: python, csv, sentence-transformers

I have a large csv file (35m rows) in the following format:

```
id, sentence, description
```

Normally in inference mode, Id like to use  model like so:

```
for iter_through_csv:
    model = SentenceTransformer('flax-sentence-embeddings/some_model_here', device=gpu_id)
    encs = model.encode(row[1], normalize_embeddings=True)
```

But since I have GPUs Id like to batch it. However, the size is large (35m), so I do not want to read in memory and batch.

I am struggling to find a template to batch csv on huggingface.
What is the most optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using buffer reading from file, for example, via pandas, you just skip rows and read another batch_size rows

```
pd.read_csv(path,
            skiprows=index * batch_size + 1,
            chunksize=batch_size,
            names=['data'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the csv to a huggingface [dataset](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/index). This allows you to process a large dataset without loading the full thing into memory. You can [map](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/process#map) your embedding function along the dataset to compute embeddings without having to keep all of them in memory.